# How to include files relative to a file's directory

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, themes

I'm building a small plugin into a WordPress theme like `wp-content/themes/my-theme/inc/my-plugin`.

I'm wondering how to include files inside this folder that are relative to the main plugin file `wp-content/themes/my-theme/inc/my-plugin/my-plugin.php`.

For example, in `my-plugin.php`, I need to include `wp-content/themes/my-theme/inc/my-plugin/css/style.css`.

I'm looking for something like `wp_enqueue_style( 'my-plugin-style', plugins_url( '/css/style.css', __FILE__ ) );` but I want it to be only relative to the `my-plugin.php` directory and NOT relative to the WordPress plugin directory OR theme directory. This way I can make it a separate plugin too if I want, without changing any code.

Please do not ask why I'm building this into the theme or that it should be a separate plugin. Just looking for possible solutions.

Thanks!

Comment: try replacing the call to `plugins_url( '/css/style.css', __FILE__ )` with `__DIR__ . '/css/styles.css'`

Comment: @Bryan close but I get something like `<link rel="stylesheet" id="my-plugin-style" href="http://www.my-domain.com/nfs/c10/h06/mnt/147028/domains/www.my-domain.com/html/wp-content/themes/my-theme/inc/my-plugin/css/style.css?ver=4.9.4" type="text/css" media="all">`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [plugin_dir_path](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugin_dir_path/) to get the file path of the current file the code is executed in.

*The “plugin” part of the name is misleading – it can be used for any file, and will not return the directory of a plugin unless you call it within a file in the plugin’s base directory.*

```
 plugin_dir_path( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . 'css/style.css';
```

Here's an example of how I would enqueue a script which will work anywhere.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/script-name.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );
```

Comment: Unfortunately this gives the same output as Bryan's answer above.

Comment: I will give you the directory path not the url.

Comment: It gives me `<link rel="stylesheet" id="my-plugin-style" href="http://www.my-domain.com/nfs/c10/h06/mnt/147028/domains/www.my-domain.com/html/wp-content/themes/my-theme/inc/my-plugin/css/style.css?ver=4.9.4" type="text/css" media="all">`

Comment: According  to the documentation and from my experience of using it you'll get the filesystem directory path (with trailing slash).  No idea how you've managed to get it to return a URL.

Comment: @TroyTempleman I've added an example of how I always enqueue scripts to return the correct URL.

Comment: I don't know either. I even tried removing all other code in `my-plugin.php` so there's no risk of conflicts and only linking to `style.css`. Same result.

Comment: @AndrewSchultz Your example doesn't use `plugin_dir_path`, it uses `plugin_dir_url` which is fine for plugins but doesn't work outside the plugins directory.